# Is there an Enum type in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I just wondered if there is an `EnumType` in PySpark/Spark.
I want to add constraints on `StringType`s (or other types as well) to have certain values only in my `DataFrame`'s schema.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723938/enum-equivalent-in-spark-dataframe-parquet